# Reading a graph for dispersion relation of normal modes in 3D lattice

Tags: solid-state-physics, crystals, vibrations, phonons

I'm trying to interpret graphs of [this](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/45/Phonon_dispersion_relations_in_GaAs.png) type. In this example, dispersion relation $\omega = \omega(k)$ for some waves corresponding to lattice vibrations in GaAs are shown.

What is uncomprehensible to me is the abscissa that should represent the 3D wave vector $\vec{k}$ in some way. Units in these graphs are never displayed. Some points along the axis are marked with letters that represent ["high symmetry points"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brillouin_zone#Critical_points) or "critical points" in Brillouin zone of the 3D lattice and therefore specific value for $\vec{k}$.

QUESTIONS:

a) How are the "high symmetry points" chosen? Do they have particular properties?

b) Which value of $\vec{k}$ (modulus and direction) does correpond to a point on the horizontal axis of the [example graph](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/45/Phonon_dispersion_relations_in_GaAs.png) that is found between two high symmetry points?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at a Brillouin zone for zinc blende crystals. You’ll see that it’s a polyhedron. The “high-symmetry” points are just points such as the center of the polyhedron ($\Gamma$) or corners or centers of faces, etc. In the $\omega$ vs. $k$ plot, a region between labeled lines is taken to be a straight-line path within the 3D Brillouin zone between the two labeled points. So, you can quickly see from the graph how the frequency varies as $k$ goes from $\Gamma$ to $L$, for instance. This is easier than representing the complete $\omega(\mathbf{k})$ function,which would be a 4D plot.

This type of 2D plot is a simplification, but it’s useful because all the interesting things (such as maxima and minima of bands) happen at the high-symmetry points, or at least somewhere on a line between them.